# Angular sliding button

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to create an Angular sliding button component just like the image shown below. I had go through all kind of research but there is no any reference for angular, only have vue and react.

I would like to execute a function after the button is slide to the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/demo/swipe 






we willl achieve this in mobile apps by using gesture detector

if you want to achieve this in web 

try this as a reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73697148/angular-sliding-button#
```